# Flink dashboard on GCP not working as expected on default port

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-flink

I have TCP port on 8081 enabled and I can see the details on my VM.

```
    sudo netstat -tulpn 
    Active Internet connections (only servers)
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      857/sshd: /usr/sbin 
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      839/exim4           
    tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:6123          :::*                    LISTEN      94973/java          
    tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      70045/apache2       
    tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          :::*                    LISTEN      94973/java          
    tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      857/sshd: /usr/sbin 
    tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      839/exim4           
    tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:40603         :::*                    LISTEN      94973/java          
    tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:35103         :::*                    LISTEN      94973/java          
    udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           507/chronyd         
    udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           336/dhclient        
    udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                507/chronyd         
    udp6       0      0 fe80::4001:aff:feb6:546 :::*                                438/dhclient
```

I also configured my cluster on two workers and started the taskmamanger. But, I can't access the dashboard on 8081. When I try to telnet it says connection refused.

Comment: Telnet from where? The Java process is listening on `127.0.0.1:8081` which means that it only accepts connections from applications inside the OS. Change the listening address to `0.0.0.0:8081` and create an allow ingress VPC firewall rule for port 8081.

Comment: @JohnHanley When I do a telnet on my external IP, I see a connection error.

Trying IP...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

I had the ingress all ports

Comment: @JohnHanley Also how can I change the listening address from localhost to allow all with 0.0.0.0. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: I do not know Apache Flink. The documentation should cover that detail.